# Storing child data elements that are globally accessible

Tags: jquery

This piece of code, stores the div elements under div="eyes" in "items"

```
$items = $('.slideshow #eyes > div');
```

However, i want to store div elements, dynamically, based on the parent div.
For instance, i tried something using 'this', without success :

```
$('.slideshow').click( function() {
  $items = $('$(this) > div');
});
```

Also, how to make the resultant "items", globally accessible?

Comment: What do you mean store elements based on the parent div? What specifically about the parent div? You mean you want to pass in the ID of a div and load all of the child divs in to an items collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var items; //declare items outside of the function scope so it is globally available.

function SomeFunction(divID){

  items = $("#" + divID + " > div"); //select all child divs of whatever div you are referencing.

}
```

This should give you a global items variable that contains a list of div elements that are children of whatever div you passed to the SomeFunction method.